# Finding the limit of $\frac{\cos(\pi n)}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know all of the tests for limits of series but unsure which one to use for this?

Can I use the comparison test and compare it with $\frac{1}{n^2}$ or should I use a different approach?

Edit: Perhaps someone could edit the title in latex to make it easier to read?

Comment: $\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n$

Comment: I thought so, so I need to use the alternating series test?

Comment: It would be suffice :)

Comment: A series test, to determine the limit of a sequence? What for?

Comment: for all the redaction it seems like the OP is looking for convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{n\pi}}{n^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$
The alternating test would be suffice to proof the series converges.

If what do you want is the value:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}$$

First:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

The first sum in the decomposition is then:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{24}$$

Then the second sum in the decomposition:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

And finally:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{\pi^2}{8}=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use the squeeze method

$$0\le\left\vert\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{n^2}\right\rvert\le\frac1{n^2}$$